# Выдает ошибку в 'initials2'

Tags: c

```
#define _CRT_SECURE_NO_WARNINGS

#include <stdio.h>  
#include <locale.h> 

int main()
{
    setlocale(LC_ALL, "Rus");

    char name1[7], name2[9], name3[12];
    char initials1[6], initials2[6], initials3[6];
    unsigned short year1, year2, year3;
    float number1[7], number2[7], number3[7];

    printf("1. Введите: фамилию, инициалы, год рожд., оклад > ");
    scanf("%s %s %hu %f ", name1, initials1, &year1, &number1);
    printf("\n2. Введите: фамилию, инициалы, год рожд., оклад > ");
    scanf("%s %s %hu %f", name2, initials2, &year2, &number2);
}
```

Ошибка:

> Run-Time Check Failure #2 - Stack around the variable 'initials2' was corrupted

В чем ошибка у меня? Я ввожу в первое:
Иванов
И.И.
1975
517.50
Во второе ввожу: Петренко
П.П.
1956
219.10
Но ошибку мне выдает на "П.П." и выкидывает из программы.

Comment: А **что именно** вводите? укажите точно - скорее всего выходите за границы выделенной памяти... Да, и зачем вам *массивы* `number#`, а не просто числа?

Comment: Я ввожу в первое: Иванов , И.И. , 1975 , 517.50 . Во второе ввожу: Петренко , П.П. , 1956 , 219.10 . Хорошо, массив щас уберу. А выхода за границу не вижу где( можете указать, пожалуйста?

Comment: Под вопросом кнопка "править", используйте ее для уточнения вопроса

Comment: Нет. Ввожу все по отдельности. Фамилию ввел - нажимаю ентер. Ввел инициалы - ентер. и так далее.

Comment: А разве `setlocale(LC_ALL, "Rus");` не превращает плавающую точку в плавающую запятую?

Comment: @EOF Наметанный у вас глаз :)

Comment: @EOF, можете пояснить, пожалуйста, что это значит? И что мне изменить? Я не очень разбираюсь в языках программирования. Просто у меня без этой команды выдавалась каша, а не русские буквы.

Comment: Из-за `setlocale`, десятичные дроби нужно вводить не с точкой, а с запятой. Было `517.50`, стало `517,50`. Ведь Вы сами установили русскую локаль.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Вызов `setlocale(LC_ALL, "Rus");` установил русскую локаль. В Вашем случае это значит, что в числах с плавающей точкой теперь будет использоваться запятая вместо точки. Теперь точка не является частью числа, и поэтому при чтении введённых данных, при обнаружении точки в Вашем вводе, `scanf` думает, что прочитала число до конца и оставляет точку (и всё после неё) в потоке ввода.

Если желательно при Rus локали оставить как разделитель целой части точку, то после `setlocale(LC_ALL, "Rus");` надо вызвать `setlocale(LC_NUMERIC, "C");`.¹

---

<sup>¹ Спасибо [@avp](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/users/232/avp) за доп. информацию.</sup>